# Update status bar text colour in real time as view changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

This might be a beginner question, but I noticed something interesting in the new Apple Music app. When switching from one view to another, the status bar text colour seems to change in real time rather than all at once when the next view loads.

Check out this screen recording to see what I mean:
http://f.cl.ly/items/2A0a3Q3i2O2d2O3u3q1m/statusBar_1.mp4

Closeup: http://f.cl.ly/items/182r3n3Z1m1y0y1W0j2J/statusBar_2.mov

How would I achieve this same effect? For instance, when transitioning to another view controller modally, how would I get the status bar style to change dynamically like this rather than when the next view loads? Is it even possible? Is Apple using some private API, or is it just a really simple trick I'm missing? Sorry if this is a beginner question, but I don't think I've ever seen another app do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you’re missing—there’s definitely no API to do that. I’ve seen a couple of third-party apps do something similar, probably by finding the status bar window, snapshotting it, and doing clever things with the resulting image, but that’s pretty fragile. As always, if you’d like an API for something, you should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just filed an enhancement request. I feel like this should really be default behaviour for view controller transitions.

Comment: by the way, apple has complete control over their software and can pretty much do whatever they want. Most likely they are changing the colors on the fly with code and not some screenshoting. That code maybe completely private to us developers. Just a hunch

Comment: Sam B: you’re correct, which is why I specified that it was *third-party* apps that might be doing the snapshotting shenanigans.

Comment: Even Apple's implementation seems a bit fragile. If you exit the app and come back to the Now Playing screen, the status bar text turns black. If you enable VPN, the VPN icon jumps between the left side and right as you switch between views.

Comment: Sounds worth filing a bug about. :)